# Turbolinks 5 adapter to react native

Tags: android, ios, react-native, turbolinks

I have seen the idea of make hybrids apps with turbolinks 5, I think this is a really good idea. But in this case I need to create some views in native (or the most similar to native), create this webview needed by turbolinks 5 with react native would be the solution.

Here is a great talk about how to do this natively in  android and iOS :
https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=SWEts0rlezA

However, is there an equivalent tutorial or information about using turbolinks for react-native webviews?